# Specify root context for web application in wildfly 8 at deployment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

Is it possible to override the root context specified in WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml at deploy time?

I have this jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>my-context</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

And I want to be able to deploy the application with different root context in in e.g. /another-context for some of my environments, but keep /my-context in other environments.

Comment: Symlinking/renaming war file to ROOT.war overrides context from jboss-web.xml and deployes to root context (/). Do Wildfly have simliar functionality as --contextroot for Glassfish to be able to set other contexts than root?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via [WildFly Maven Plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/) (as part of your CI job) or using the WildFly CLI.

The maven variant would be like the following command:

```
org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:deploy-only
    -Dwildfly.deployment.filename=app.war 
    -Dwildfly.deployment.runtime.name=appcontext.war
```

The app will be deployed under **/appcontext**.

Note, you should remove the **context-root** from your *jboss-web.xml* otherwise this value will win always.

The CLI variant could look like ([documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Application+deployment)):

```
[dply@as wildfly-8.2.0.Final]$ bin/jboss-cli.sh 
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] connect
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] deploy /path/to/app.war --runtime-name=appcontext.war
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing this, you could combine maven profiles (e.g. "my-context" and "another-context") and maven resource filtering as explained here: [Maven resource filters](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

It certainly takes a little bit of time until everything works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

if you have a EAR file you need to define it at your application.xml

```
<module>
  <web>
     <web-uri>webapp.war</web-uri>
     <context-root>/my-context</context-root>
  </web>
</module>
```