# JHipster production WAR is missing WEB-INF config files

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to deploy my JHipster app to Wildfly and am following the recommendation in this post :

[How to add context file from Wildfly to JHipster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886587/how-to-add-context-file-from-wildfly-to-jhipster)

... for including jboss-web.xml and jboss-deployment-structure.xml in the WAR file.  I've created a WEB-INF folder under src/main/webapp and placed the two config files there:

[image]

However when I run the command for generting the production WAR file **using Gradle** (./gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage), the WAR file contains neither jboss-web.xml or jboss-deployment-structure.xml in the WEB-INF folder.  Do I need to modify build.gradle to ensure that it grabs the files I've placed in WEB-INF when generating the WAR file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gradle ***war*** task needs to be told where the WEB-INF config files are located.

**build.gradle:**

```
war {
    webInf { from 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF' }
}
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html.